# apt-get,dpkg not working in ubuntu20.4

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

```
    crypto@Stock:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
[sudo] password for crypto: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package dpkg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'dpkg' has no installation candidate
crypto@Stock:~$ apt-get upgrade -y
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
crypto@Stock:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
    crypto@Stock:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Please show output of `apt policy dpkg`

Comment: Download the package from https://pkgs.org/download/dpkg